# What is the probability of drawing five cards with different ranks from a deck of cards

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

From the standard 52-card deck, 5 cards are drawn randomly and is not put back.
What is the probability that none of the ranks are the same?
An example is 3, 5, 6, J, K.

I have tried this method, taking the product of each draw, but don't know if it's a valid method:

1st draw : $\frac{52}{52}$

2nd draw : 1 - $\frac{3}{51}$ = $\frac{48}{51}$ (Because there now is 51 cards left and three are bad.)

3rd draw : 1 - $\frac{6}{50}$ = $\frac{44}{50}$

4th draw : 1 - $\frac{9}{49}$ = $\frac{40}{49}$

5th draw : 1 - $\frac{12}{48}$ = $\frac{36}{48}$

P(x) = $\frac{52 * 48 * 44 * 40 * 36}{52 * 51 * 50 * 49 * 48}$ = $\frac{2112}{4165}$ ~= 50,7 %.

To me this seems like a weird and wrong answer, and I don't know how I would solve this problem generally.

Could someone please explain? :) Got exams in 12 hours, and got a feeling I need to know this :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of ways to pick 5 cards (possible scenarios) : $\binom{52}{5}$

We have to pick 5 different types , there are 13 types , therefore:  $\binom{13}{5}$ possibles set of 5 different types.

We have 4 cards of each type in the deck , therefore we have $4^5$ possibilities to represent one sequence of 5 different types .

Finally , the probability is $\frac{\binom{13}{5}*4^5 }{\binom{52}{5}}$